# Styling new developer portal in Azure API Management Services

Tags: css, azure, azure-api-management

How can I modify the colors of the navbar links in the **new** developer portal, for the layouts?

So far I've tried the designer tool that comes with the portal, with no luck. I've also tried cloning the git repository for the APIM instance, but only seem to find settings for the legacy portal.

No guide I've found so far more that scratches the surface of how to style the new portal.

Any hint or idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to clone the repository to change any styling.
All styles can be changed in the Style guide.

Also, you can check docs https://aka.ms/apimdocs/customizeportal

But the main idea is:

- to change the style for **navbar link** for the **Regular page menu** appearance on the Style guide page
  (Style guide -> menus nav link -> Navigation link editor)
- or create a separate appearance for menu (Style guide -> menus -> add appearance)
- open the menu editor for the layout (Layouts -> select menu on a layout -> open menu editor)
- select the required appearance in Appearance dropdown

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by removing the default navbar widget and replacing it with a horizontal custom menu.

Comment: @CristofferRyrberg I am migrating from deprecated developer portal to new developer portal. So I want the same design of deprecated portal to new one. I have tried but nothing found to achieve this. Please help me on this. 

How we can use custom css, javascript and html in pages.